# Bring all folders to parent folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, script, macros

So i have a bunch of folders that all have 1 folder in side of them with the name of a song. Inside that folder is the song itself. Is there a script that can delete the parent folder and just use the song folder. For example, i want to "c:\song1\yourvoice\song.ogg" to become c:\yourvoice\song.ogg" along with every folder in the directory. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One way of managing this is as follows:

1. In a CMD Prompt, run "dir /s *.ogg > filelist.txt"
2. Now that you have a list of directories which contain your files, you can make this into a "move" script by removing the parent directory.

Comment: I got impatient and did something stupid. I searched for *. * and copied everything. Then I pasted it into the Parent directory. Afterwards I deleted everything extra. It took a bit but it worked kind of.